# Prove that the matrix A is diagonalizable if $-4bc < (a-d)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that matrix A is diagonalizable
if $-4bc < (a - d)^2$ and is not diagonalizable if $-4bc > (a - d)^2$

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
  a & b\\
  c & d 
 \end{bmatrix}$

I'm not sure how to start. I was thinking of taking the inverse of A but I'm sure if that's the right approach.

Comment: Hint: Can you find an expression for the eigenvalues?

Comment: Diagonalizability and invertibility don't have a lot to do with each other. There are plenty of matrices that are invertible that aren't diagonalizable and vice versa. Also, do you mean diagonalizable over the reals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to work in the field of real numbers. In this case you have the following

1) If the matrix is diagonalizable, then it must have both the roots real

2) If the matrix has eigenvalues that are not repeated,  then it can be diagonalized with the following additional comment: If the eigenvalues are **not** real, the diagonalization would require complex numbers.

3) The only real matrices with repeated eigenvalues that is also diagonalizable are multiples of the identity matrix, i.e. diagonal matrices with equal values on the diagonal.

To OP:
In one of your comments you have 
$$
\lambda^2-(a+b)\lambda+ad+bc$$
It should be
$$
\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc$$
So for real roots that are distinct, you need
$$
(a+d)^2 -4(ad - bc) = a^2 + 2 a d + d^2 - 4 a d + 4bc = (a-d)^2 + 4 bc \gt 0$$
or
$$ (a-d)^2 \gt -4bc$$

Note $a=d, b=1, c=0$ is *not* diagonalizable. So you cannot change the $\gt$ to $\ge$.
Also, $a=d, b=c=0$ is diagonalizable. So
$$
\text{If }(a-d)^2 = -4bc, \text{ the matrix is diagonalizable if and only if $b=0$ and $c=0$}$$

** Added in reply to OP **

Let $\Delta$ be the discriminant

There are 3 cases

1. $\Delta < 0$. Both the eigenvalues are complex so matrix can not be diagonalized.
2. $\Delta >0$. Both eigenvalues are real and distinct (different). Matrix *can* be diagonalized
3. $\Delta=0$. Both eigenvalues are equal. Then there are two cases: Matrix is diagonal, i.e. $b=c=0$. Matrix is not diagonal $b \ne 0$ or $c \ne 0$. In the first case the matrix is diagonalizable (it is already diagonal!). In the second case the matrix cannot be diagonalized.

Comment: I just don't understand how you get >0 from = 0 from the discriminant.

Comment: You do not want =0. I will update my answer

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1:** the eigenvalues of a matrix are precisely the roots of the equation $\det(A - tI) = 0$.  So, for this particular case, the eigenvalues of $A$ are the values of $t$ for which
$$
\det(A - t\cdot I_{2\times 2}) = \det \pmatrix{
a - t&b\\
c& d-t
} = 0
$$

**Hint 2:** Any $n \times n$ matrix with $n$ distinct eigenvalues is diagonalizable.  Any matrix with no (real) eigenvalues is certainly not diagonalizable (over the reals).

Comment: I get $\lambda^2-(a+b)\lambda+ad+bc$ = 0
Instead of $t$ I put $\lambda$

Comment: Check your work. You should have $$\lambda^2 - (a+b)\lambda + (ad - bc) = 0$$ (see the minus sign towards the end).  Now, we have a quadratic equation for $\lambda$.  What does the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of this quadratic equation tell you?

Comment: We then get $(a-d)^2-4bc=0$ as the discriminant. If this is the case, I don't see how we get $-4bc < (a-d)^2$ Since we get $(a-d)^2$=$-4bc$

Comment: What am I missing here?